# How can I access a variable outside block?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

Following code doesn't work properly.

```
  func convertToStreet(location:CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLPlacemark {

    var tempLocation = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)

    var temPlacemark:CLPlacemark?

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(tempLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in

        temPlacemark = (placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark)
        println(temPlacemark!.thoroughfare)

    })

    return temPlacemark!
}
```

Println inside the completion handler works properly, but the value of temPlacemark is nil at the end of code. Why does that happen? I thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It happens because at the return time, it is still working on it. If you put thread to wait certain amount of time you will get the correct value. Also, if you put breakpoint inside completition handler and outside you will see that outside part is executed first.

Answer (score 2):

It's because that `completionHandler` is called asynchronously. For that to work you should have a callback block in your custom function to return the value once you get it from the `CLGeocoder`.

Something like this:

```
func convertToStreet(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, completionHandler: (placemark: CLPlacemark!, error: NSError!) -> Void) {
    let tempLocation = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(tempLocation) { placemarks, error in
        completionHandler(placemark: placemarks?.first as CLPlacemark?, error: error)
    }
}
```

You'd then call it like so:

```
convertToStreet(location.coordinate) { placemark, error in
    if placemark != nil {
        // use `placemark` here
        println(placemark.thoroughfare)
    } else {
        println(error)
    }
}

// but don't use `placemark` here
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rob! I was just trying to give an overall idea of what I was proposing as a solution. But I definitely shouldn't have written that example as the language I know is Objective-C for now, not Swift.

Comment: Feel free to do it ;) @Rob

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is that the block code :

```
temPlacemark = (placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark)
println(temPlacemark!.thoroughfare)
```

will be executed later.

Meaning that the current `return` statement will always return an uninitialized value.
If you want to initialize this `var` in your block you should make it a `property` of your object.